# How to obtain an Azure Active Directory's B2C Custom attribute using GraphServiceClient?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an ADB2C list of users, for which a Custom attribute is attached. I need to programmatically obtain the attribute.

First, when I query the entry using `powershell AzureAD` extension, I can see the attribute like so (GUIDs abridged):

```
> Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 00000e9b... | select *
ExtensionProperty              : {[odata.type, Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User], [createdDateTime, 24.09.2021 6:55:48], [employeeId, ], [onPremisesDistinguishedName, ]...}
DeletionTimestamp              :
ObjectId                       : 00000e9b...
ObjectType                     : User
... some other keys ...

>> Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId  00000e9b... | select *  -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty

Key                                                   Value
---                                                   -----
odata.type                                            Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime                                       24.09.2021 6:55:48
... some other keys ...
extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId 501cd02e...
```

So there is the `extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId` with the value  `501cd02e...` that I am willing to retrieve alongside ObjectId for some further processing using C# and `GraphServiceClient`.
In a close resemblance to [this example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=csharp#request-2) I made the following code:

```
var result = await graphClient.Users
      .Request()
      .Select("id,Identities,DisplayName,extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId")
      .Top(999)
      .GetAsync();
```

Dumping the `result` to JSON, I expect to see some values of `extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId` inside a property. What I get is an array of entries like

```
{
   ... many NULL fields ...
  "Identities": [ ... meaningful data of user's email etc...],
  "Id": "00000e9b... ",
  "AdditionalData": {
    "extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId": {
      "ValueKind": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Simply put, I get the obscure `"AdditionalData": {"extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId": {"ValueKind": 3}}` but not the value of the Custom attribute. There are plenty of other fields which are typically `null`.

How can I modify the request in my code to obtain the value of the `extension_05700734c8154786b58d437faf3d30c7_customerId` in C#?

Answer (score 0):

The [extension property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0) is probably what you are looking for.

More specifically the [list extension property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples).

Example

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.ExtensionProperties
```

If you are looking for a specific extension property you can modify your query by adding the id of the extension property.

```
var result = await graphClient.Users.ExtensionProperties["{extensionProperty-id}"]
```

Comment: Regretfully `Users.ExtensionProperties` can not be found. It is different for Applications.